# Exception when using PreAuthorize annotation alongwith path-variables that contian special characters

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, path-variables

Here is my set-up:

1. We have a spring-boot application 2.6.4.
2. It has a RestController class with a GET api endpoint as `/v1/permissions/{appname}/users/{username}`, where appname and username are path-variables.
3. This controller has a `@PreAuthorize` annotation like this:
   `@PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('/v1/permissions/member', '/v1/permissions/colt')")`
4. Now when we hit the API with path `/v1/permissions/member/users/krishna` it works perfectly fine and gives us the output.
5. But when we hit the API with path `/v1/permissions/member/users/krishna@goloka.com` it gives the following error:

   ```
   org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog#log:175 - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext] with root cause |
   org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
   ```
6. After some analysis we found that the above error occurs only when we are using the "@PreAuthorize annotation" alongwith special characters in "username" path-variable, that is only this combination of annotation and path-variable gives the error.
7. But this error doesn't occur with the following combinations:

   - "@PreAuthorize annotation" and using "username" as a request-parameter with any type of special characters
   - without "@PreAuthorize annotation" and using "username" as path-variable with any type of special characters.
8. Also we tried debugging the issue and found out that it doesn't even go in any of our custom Authentication Provider or Custom filters when the exception occurs.

If it helps here is my `SecurityConfig` class:

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

        private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = { "/v3/api-docs", "/configuration/ui",
                "/swagger-resources/**", "/swagger-resources", "/configuration/security",
                "/swagger-ui/**", "/webjars/**" };

        @Override
        protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http.csrf().disable().headers().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                    .addFilterBefore(new CustomHeaderAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);

        }

        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {

            web.ignoring()

                    .antMatchers("/**/*.{js,html,css}",
                            "/error",
                            "/v3/api-docs",
                            "/configuration/ui",
                            "/swagger-resources/**",
                            "/swagger-resources",
                            "/configuration/security",
                            "/swagger-ui/**",
                            "/webjars/**",
                            "/monitor/health",
                            "/monitor/db/health");

        }

    }
```

**Now my questions are:**

1. Why does this happen?
2. How can i resolve it i.e. i want to use "@PreAuthorize annotation" in combination with path-variables only.

Thank You

Comment: And no URL encoding doesn't help. Since without PreAuthorize it works even without encoding infact encoding it also gives the same exception

Comment: `@PreAuthorize` has nothing to do with Endpoint security that is enforced in spring security filters, `@PreAuthorize` annotations are `MethodInvocation` security annotations, to be used internally to enforce security between function calls. Thats you dont see any filters etc that are being invoked. You are trying to use something for something it wasnt designed for https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/method-security.html Method security uses spring AOP and not filters

Comment: also read the docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/method-security.html#using-authorization-expression-fields-and-methods `hasAnyAuthority` takes an Authority as parameter, like `ROLE_USER` or `ROLE_ADMIN` so for example: `hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_USER", "ROLE_ADMIN")` are your role names url-paths?

Comment: also what is this? `CustomHeaderAuthenticationFilter` if you tell me its a custom JWT filter i suggest you delete it, and use the built in JWTfilter that ships with Spring Security because writing custom security is bad practice

Comment: @Toerktumlare Thanks for pointing to the documentation and the comments. So, if you would be kind enough to tell me exactly what's wrong?

Comment: @Toerktumlare I am using `hasAnyAuthority` not `hasAnyRole` so these are not role-names but permissions and i suppose they can be any string. For the purpose of the question i can change it to normal string and the problem still persists.

Comment: @Toerktumlare
No, its not a CustomJWTFilter. Are you saying this can cause problems? I understand the implications for using a custom security filter.